# Cypress cross-origin iframe for Stripe not working with Firebase error

Tags: firebase, iframe, stripe-payments, cross-domain, cypress

I'm working on a project which uses Firestore as well as Stripe for the checkout process. My tests were all passing until I got to the checkout part, which uses an iframe that Stripe creates. Naturally, because of it being a cross-domain iframe, I can't access/modify the input contents directly.

I followed the instructions on [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1763#issuecomment-530837349), as well as added `"chromeWebSecurity": false` to `cypress.json` in order to try and bypass the security but I am now getting all tests failing because of aborted XHR calls (namely `Firestore` calls). Any ideas?

I get: `Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

This was working before adding the config above, so I can't even test if it helped with the original issue (Stripe) because it will immediately fail with those errors above.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. If you disable web security you can not make protected firestore requests and if you don't disable it you can not interact with the stripe iframe. 

If you do figure this out [this article](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/02/12/working-with-iframes-in-cypress) noted a useful library for simplifying the interaction with the iframe.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-iframe

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is pretty good:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-plugin-stripe-elements

```js
// Stripe card input element uses iframe
cy.fillElementsInput('cardNumber', '4242424242424242');
cy.fillElementsInput('cardExpiry', '1234');
cy.fillElementsInput('cardCvc', '123');
cy.fillElementsInput('postalCode', '12345');
```